# Genymotion + Vorlon not working, but iOS SIm + Vorlon is fine

Tags: android, debugging, remote-debugging, genymotion, vorlon

I have vorlon up and running in a webview successfully and can connect/debug  the iOS sim. However, I can't get it to connect with Genymotion running the same code.

I'm guessing it has something to do with Genymotion using VBox for the Android emulation and it's not set up to resolve.

I tried both localhost:1337 as well as put it up on an AWS instance with no luck. I was able to connect to the dashboard in both cases, but the webview was not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently VirtualBox has a default network configuration of **host-only**, so you have to reference `localhost` files via your IP *relative to VirtualBox*.

Run `ifconfig vboxnet0` to get the settings:

```
$ ifconfig vboxnet0
    vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00
    inet 192.168.56.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

`192.168.56.1:1337` will be the IP (with `Vorlon`'s port, `1337`.)

---

On a related note, make sure you load `Vorlon` **before** RequireJS, as it *also* uses Require to load dependencies and will get confused by the additional reference to Require.